# Firestore real-time updates with REST API

Tags: c++, rest, google-cloud-firestore

I'm developing c++ app which connects to Firestore DB via REST API. Is there any workaround to implement real-time updates when some fields in DB are modified? I'm thinking about getting collection document in certain time interval and checking whether there are any updates but it doesn't seem to be very efficient way. On the other side, the size of the downloaded data wouldn't be very large.
I know that gRPC allows using listeners, but I would prefer to stay with REST.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Firestore REST API does not implement realtime listeners. If having realtime listeners is a requirement for your use-case, you will have to use one of the SDKs or the gRPC API.